# Lagom - Testing Service Call with Headers

Tags: java, lagom

I'm trying to follow the documentation [here](http://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.2.x/java/ServiceImplementation.html) regarding "Handling headers." I can't figure out how to test service call invocation with headers. Normally, I would just do

```
service.sayHello().invoke(...)
```

I noticed that `ServerServiceCall` and `HeaderServiceCall` accept `invokeWithHeaders(...)` and my `ServiceCall` is implemented as a `HeaderServiceCall`, but whenever I try to change my service API to `ServerServiceCall` or `HeaderServiceCall`, i get:

```
 Error in custom provider, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service calls must return ServiceCall, subtypes are not allowed
```

How can I write a test that invokes the service call with custom request headers? I've tried keeping the call as `ServiceCall` in the API, implementing with `HeaderServiceCall`, and casting the call to `HeaderServiceCall` in the test, but I got a cast exception when trying to do that. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just adopted my test code to check it:

```
 public HeaderServiceCall<NewUser, RegUserStatus> addUser(String id) {

    return (reqHeaders, postedUser) -> {
        System.out.println(reqHeaders.getHeader("Referer"));
        PersistentEntityRef<UserCommand> ref = persistentEntityRegistry.refFor(UserEntity.class, id);
        return ref.ask(new UserCommand.RegisterUser(id, postedUser)).thenApply( stat -> Pair.create(ResponseHeader.OK, stat));
    };
}
```

my api:

```
ServiceCall<NewUser, RegUserStatus> addUser(String id);
```

and test:

```
@Test
public void testIt() {
    withServer(defaultSetup(), server -> {
        UsersService service = server.client(UsersService.class);
        RegUserStatus created = service.addUser("aaa").handleRequestHeader(
                rh -> rh.withHeader("Referer" ,"winter")
        ).invoke(new NewUser("aaa")).toCompletableFuture().get(5, SECONDS);
        assertEquals(true, created.ok); // default greeting

    });
}
```

Comment: You aren't actually modifying the request headers in your test.